# height not changing in scroll function

Tags: jquery, html, header, scroll

When the visitor scrolls more than 20px away from the top window position the header is supposed to shrink down in size (along with it's content). When the visitor scrolls back to the top (or <20px) the header is supposed to go back to it's original size (auto).

The header (and the content) shrinks down fine. Even the size of the img changes correctly. However, the header size does not change. It's like the header size of the if{ } condition overrides everything else.

I just want to make a simple fixed header bar that shrinks (minimizes) once you scroll down the page and flips back to it's original size if you go back to the top.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jwarddesign/NphFw/21/

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using CSS to style the small state of the header? Whenever the `scrollTop` is greater than 20px, add the small state class and whenever it's less than 20px, remove it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NphFw/23/

In relation to your problem, I'm not sure jQuery can animate to dynamic values such as `auto` or `inherit` even.